Is there a way to prevent the output of http headers from appearing in the content of a csv file?
I'm currently working in a Laravel Project with a Laravel Jetstream scaffolding with Inertia js and Vue 3. Everything is working as expected but now I need to make a downloadable CSV file.
At first I tried with fopen(), fputcsv() and fclose() PHP functions then I make it manually (concatenating strings) the file and the content get well formed but for some reason, that I do not understand, always at the end of the CSV file the HTTP headers get written! Why? and most important how can I solve this problem? I just need a clean CSV file with no http headers inside it.
Here is an example of what I'm getting inside the CSV file, always at end of the file the HTTP headers get printed:

Those HTTP header must not appear inside the CSV file content!
Here is the PHP that build and send the output of the CSV file as a downloadable response:
<?php

namespace App\Reports;

class ReporteCSV
{
    public function __construct(
        protected string $delimiter,
        protected array $headers,
        protected array|object $data,
    ) {
    }

    public function output(string $filename)
    {
        return response()->streamDownload(
            $this->processCSV2(),
            $filename,
            [
                'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
                'Content-Disposition' => "attachment; filename=\"$filename\"",
            ]
        );
    }

    private function processCSV()
    {
        $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

        fputcsv($file, $this->headers, $this->delimiter);

        foreach ($this->data as $cedula)
        {
            fputcsv($file, [$cedula], $this->delimiter);
        }

        fclose($file);
    }

    private function processCSV2()
    {
        $content = "'cedula'" . "\n";

        foreach ($this->data as $cedula)
        {
            $content .= $cedula
                    . "\n";
        }

        echo $content;
    }
}

And this is the HTML button where users can download the CSV file:

Any idea how to solve this please?

I think this is due to the nature how a stream response works did you try the download facade

Then I would need to save the file at somewhere in the storage file system and the file is for download only, it must not be stored in the storage file system.

you have two options for that. Either you place it into a temp directory. But there is also an older answer
